# Split a linked list nodes multiple data and show the resultant

Tags: java, split, linked-list, key, nodes

I want to use a text file to populate a linked list using a Java SE app. The text file has the following format:

firstnamelastname mobile home office

I want to insert these lines as nodes in the linked list! then i want to search for a specific node from the linked list that has been populated from the text file !

using firstnamelastname as a key i want to compare it with the nodes data (data is to to splitted as to compare with the "key") after finding the specific node i want to split that nodes data using split(" "); and show the resultant !!!

i just want to know about hint doing it all I will be very thankful in advance please help me out !!!

i have generated a java source code but its not working as it always give me the last nodes data so check the blunder I made if its totally wrong give any of your idea!

```
    try {
        String fullname;
        String mobile;
        String home;
        String mobile2;
        String office;

        Node current = first;

        while (current.data != key) {

            String splitter[] = current.data.split(" ");

            fullname = splitter[0];
            mobile = splitter[1];
            home = splitter[2];
            mobile2 = splitter[3];
            office = splitter[4];

            if (fullname == null ? key == null : fullname.equals(key)) {
                mobilefield.setText(mobile);
                homefield.setText(home);
                mobilefield2.setText(mobile2);
                officefield.setText(office);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(
                        "SORRY RECORD NOT LISTED IN DATABASE");
            }
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage()
                + "\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN !", "Search Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


(key is as=firstname+lastname;)
```

Comment: Do you really want to support `key == null` as valid value for `fullname`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ArrayList (needs less memory, has better performance for most operations)

Code looks ok for me, but I would not not split the `current.data` for every entry.

I would use a test like

```
if(current.data.startsWith(key)){
  String splitter[]=current.data.split(" ");

  ...

}
```

and only if this is true I would split the `current.data` because only in this case you need *mobile* *home* *office*

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is only showing the last node of the list all the time any idea or hint !!!

Comment: You never update `current.data` in the loop and at the end of the loop always `break` terminates the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Sir I actually i want to search any Node from the list containing type of data i.e. firstnamelastname mobile home
i mean to say that the Node has data with spaces and i want to search that type of data containing spaces 
so help me out in doing so pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee I beg YOU !!!